# XNA 2D Particle in 3D world

Tags: xna, 2d, 3d

Is it possible to make 2D-sprite particles in a 3D world that always face towards the camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible using sprite billboards, as demonstrated in 
[this tutorial](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/01/12/spritebatch-billboards-in-a-3d-world.aspx).